# Selenium RC and Firefox4 support

Tags: selenium-rc, firefox4

Who knows in which release of selenium server firefox4 (firefox5) works correctly. On http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html mentioned that both versions are supported, but I didn't find in release notes anything like Fixes of Firefox4 support

Answer (score 1):

The new server (`selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar`) runs with current versions of `Firefox` (8.x)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium RC 0.9.2 should run FF4

Answer (score 0):

you can download newer versions also they have only one jar file. or even edit older versions to support for newer versions of browsers ?